# How to make an eclipse template that automaticlly assign ctors parameters to class members?

Tags: java, eclipse, javassist

When i use an undefined constructor eclipse suggest this helpful assistment:
[image]

but how would i change eclipse configuration so that the templates of adding a ctor would create a constructor and auto assign the parameters to auto defined class members like this:

```
private GraphFrame graphFrame;

public MarkersLayer(GraphFrame gp) {
    this.graphFrame = gp;
}
```

this seem not too much to ask as the auto assist is capable of such nice things...

so is it possible? if it is how can it be done?

also, if its not hard and complex, how can one add an option to that assist window so that it would suggest to either create a constructor with all assignments or without any,so i can choose whats best for me?

Answer (score 2):

Right-click within your editor to select `Source > Generate Constructor using Fields`

[image: Generate Constructor]

I also prefer to select `Omit call to default constructor super()` on the pop-up dialog.

Comment: although this is great, i preffer going with java assist templates for learnning purposes and because it is few clicks better :)

Comment: @OfekRon Template would probably not work here because there's no template variable that evaluates to member fields (unless it already knows their type). You can check that here: `Java > Editor > Templates > New > Insert variable`

Comment: Eclipse menu `Source > Generate Constructor using Fields` will create the constructor if field is already there.But in case of `Fast Code Eclipse Plugin` template `Create Field and Constructor` ,it will create the field and constructor at a time.